# How to get item size in Vaadin8 combobox?

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin8

I'm trying to show a pop-up if there is no any item in Vaadin8 combobox. But there is no getItems() or size() methods.

here is my code, if branch size = 0 I want to push a notification to user.

```
        cbxBranch = new ComboBox<>();
        cbxBranch.setPlaceholder("Select a branch");
        cbxBranch.setItemCaptionGenerator(Branch::getBranchName);
        cbxBranch.setEmptySelectionAllowed(false);
        cbxBranch.setItems(getBranches());
        cbxBranch.addFocusListener(e -> {
            //this line just a sample..
            System.out.println(cbxBranch.getDataProvider().size());
        });
```

UPDATE:

```
cbxBranch.addFocusListener(e -> {
    if (((ListDataProvider<Branch>) cbxBranch.getDataProvider()).getItems().isEmpty()) {
       Notification.show("You don't have a branch!", Type.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vaadin 8 uses `DataProvider`s for item components like `Grid`, `TreeGrid` or `ComboBox`. The `setItems` method is a convenience method to set a `ListDataProvider` with your array/collection to the combo box. Therefore, you can call `getDataProvider`, cast to `ListDataProvider` and call `getItems` (see java doc [here](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.3/com/vaadin/data/provider/ListDataProvider.html#getItems--)).